# How to pass the name of environment variable as an argument?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch.bat with one input argument `%1`. I want to start the script as: `batch.bat PATH`. I would like this to display the PATH environment variable with `echo`.

I tried:

```
@echo %1
```

```
E:\>batch.bat PATH
PATH
```

but I would like to have the content of PATH environment variable.

```
E:\>batch.bat PATH
C:\Windows;
```

Comment: Would `Set %1 2>Nul` be acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need delayed expansion to output a variable referenced by a cmd line argument.
This batch uses two different methods for this,

- a pseudo call with doubled percent signs (which forces the parser to evaluate the line twice, on first pass reducing two `%%` to one in 2nd pass the other vars are already expanded) and
- using the `!` instead the normal single percent sign with a prior command `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\10\SO_50280684.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo(%1
Echo(!%1!
Call Echo(%%%1%%
```

I use the command separator `(` instead off a space to suppress an `Echo is off` message incase of an empty var.

Sample with command

```
>SO_50280684.cmd PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
AMD64
AMD64
```

Comment: You just need `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion`
`@ECHO !%1!`

Comment: You **did** read my answer? That's exactly one of the examples above.